# Help replicating this Document Design

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, layout

I want to replicate this document layout. I tried to reach the author, but did not get any positive response.

[image]

[image: Main Matter Header]

What I got so far is the header. But mine is statical and I want a dynamic header (adjusted to the section margins).

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{midnightgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.29, 0.33}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north west)+(0.25in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(0.65in,-0.75in)$);
    \fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north west)+(2.5in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.6in,-0.75in)$);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries, minimum size=1in, inner xsep=5mm] at ($(current page.north west)+(-0.1in,-0.05in)$){\thepage};
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries, minimum size=1in] at ($(current page.north west)+(2.6in,-0.075in)$) {\rightmark};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fancyhead[CE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north west)+(0.6in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-2.25in,-0.75in)$);
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north east)+(-0.65in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.25in,-0.75in)$);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries, minimum size=1in, inner xsep=5mm] at ($(current page.north east)+(-1in,-0.05in)$){\thepage};
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries, minimum size=1in] at ($(current page.north west)+(0.65in,-0.075in)$) {\leftmark};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter[Hola Mundo]{Hola Mundo}
\lipsum[1-9]
\section{La prueba na' ma'}

\chapter[Hola de Nuevo]{Hola Mundo... de Nuevo}
\lipsum[10-19]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code of @marmot, I added some missing parts. Please see the MWE later.

To recreate the shown structure of a document you need to add some code to your given MWE:

1. Add `\usepackage{multicol}` in your preamble and then add the following code to get a TOC in two columns:

   ```
   \begin{multicols}{2} % <================================================
   \tableofcontents % <====================================================
   \end{multicols} % <=====================================================
   ```
2. I added `\maketitle` to your code to get the title of the document.
3. To be able to add easily an complete dummy document I changed `\usepackage{lipsum}` to

   ```
   \usepackage{blindtext} % <========================== \Blinddocument
   ```

   Remember to change `\lipsum...` to `\blindtext` ...
4. To get your wanted header on chapter pages etc., too, you have to define

   ```
   \fancypagestyle{plain}{% <==============================================
   ```

   (see the full code in the following MWE).
5. Please see that I added at the end of your text `\Blinddocument` to get a better filled TOC for showing the two column TOC.
6. Have you noticed the warnings you got because you are using a KOMA-Script class with `fancyhdr` and `titlesec`? KOMA-Script has an own way to build headers with package `scrlayer-scrpage` (please see documentation with `texdoc KOMA-Script` on your terminal/console). You should consider to change to that package but that was not the question here (If you can not do it by your own, ask a new question and show what you have tried so far ...).

The complete corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % <=========================== better use scrlayer-scrpage
\usepackage{titlesec} % <=========================== see warnings in log file
\usepackage{multicol} % <===============================================
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext} % <========================== \Blinddocument

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{midnightgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.29, 0.33}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north west)+(0.25in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(0.65in,-0.75in)$)
node[midway,text=white, font=\large\bfseries] {\thepage};
\fill[midnightgreen] ([yshift=-0.35in]current page.north-|current page text area.west)
coordinate (TL)
rectangle ([yshift=-0.75in]current page.north-|current page text area.east);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries,text
height=0.2in,inner xsep=1em] at (TL) {\rightmark}; 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[CE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north east)+(-0.65in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.25in,-0.75in)$)
node[midway,text=white, font=\large\bfseries] {\thepage};
\fill[midnightgreen] ([yshift=-0.35in]current page.north-|current page text area.west)
coordinate (TL)
rectangle ([yshift=-0.75in]current page.north-|current page text area.east);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries,text height=0.2in,inner xsep=1em] 
at (TL) {\leftmark};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% <==============================================
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north west)+(0.25in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(0.65in,-0.75in)$)
node[midway,text=white, font=\large\bfseries] {\thepage};
\fill[midnightgreen] ([yshift=-0.35in]current page.north-|current page text area.west)
coordinate (TL)
rectangle ([yshift=-0.75in]current page.north-|current page text area.east);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries,text
height=0.2in,inner xsep=1em] at (TL) {\rightmark}; 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[CE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north east)+(-0.65in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.25in,-0.75in)$)
node[midway,text=white, font=\large\bfseries] {\thepage};
\fill[midnightgreen] ([yshift=-0.35in]current page.north-|current page text area.west)
coordinate (TL)
rectangle ([yshift=-0.75in]current page.north-|current page text area.east);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries,text height=0.2in,inner xsep=1em] 
at (TL) {\leftmark};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}


\begin{document}

\maketitle % <==========================================================
\begin{multicols}{2} % <================================================
\tableofcontents % <====================================================
\end{multicols} % <=====================================================
\chapter[Hola Mundo]{Hola Mundo}
\blindtext
\section{La prueba na' ma'}

\chapter[Hola de Nuevo]{Hola Mundo... de Nuevo}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument % <======================================================
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: toc]

and an usual chapter page:

[image: usual chapter page]

Answer (score 6):

With `tikzpagenodes` you can adjust things to the width of the actual page. It has the node `current page text area`, which is a rectangle that covers the text area.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\definecolor{gmitblue}{RGB}{93,138,168}
\definecolor{midnightgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.29, 0.33}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[CO]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north west)+(0.25in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west)+(0.65in,-0.75in)$)
node[midway,text=white, font=\large\bfseries] {\thepage};
\fill[midnightgreen] ([yshift=-0.35in]current page.north-|current page text area.west)
coordinate (TL)
rectangle ([yshift=-0.75in]current page.north-|current page text area.east);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries,text
height=0.2in,inner xsep=1em] at (TL) {\rightmark}; 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[CE]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\fill[midnightgreen] ($(current page.north east)+(-0.65in,-0.35in)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-0.25in,-0.75in)$)
node[midway,text=white, font=\large\bfseries] {\thepage};
\fill[midnightgreen] ([yshift=-0.35in]current page.north-|current page text area.west)
coordinate (TL)
rectangle ([yshift=-0.75in]current page.north-|current page text area.east);
\node[anchor=north west, text=white, font=\large\bfseries,text height=0.2in,inner xsep=1em] 
at (TL) {\leftmark};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}

\title{A reasonably long title}
\date{\today}
\author{The author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter[Hola Mundo]{Hola Mundo}
\lipsum[1-9]
\section{La prueba na' ma'}

\chapter[Hola de Nuevo]{Hola Mundo\dots\space de Nuevo}
\lipsum[10-29]
\end{document}
```

[image]